# How we can use the BatchingRabbitTemplate to read the messages as a batch from the RabbitMQ queue?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I am trying the scenario where I need to read a batch of messages from the queue 
e,g,.  There are 100 messages in the queue and I want to take 10 messages from the queue in a single call.

the `BatchingRabbitTemplate` provides the functionality of sending messages into RabbitMQ as a batch. Can we use same for reading the messages from the queue as a batch without using `BatchingRabbitTemplate` for publishing the messages?

Answer (score 2):

The Listener Container automatically "de-batchs" those message. See [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#template-batching).

If you need just receive them as single batch message, you should switch off the option on the container via:

```
/**
 * Determine whether or not the container should de-batch batched
 * messages (true) or call the listener with the batch (false). Default: true.
 * @param deBatchingEnabled the deBatchingEnabled to set.
 */
public void setDeBatchingEnabled(boolean deBatchingEnabled)
```

But, eh, you can use standard `RabbitTemplate.receive()` and and that will return single batch message for you.

To de-batch and receive message one by one you should go to the Listener Container anyway.

Comment: hi Artem, thanks for your response, but in our case the messages can not be published into the queue as a batch, but i want to read messages in a batch with specific number of messages from the queue in each batch.

Comment: M-m-m. No, there is no such a functionality. Only one message can be read at a time from the queue. And it is on the protocol level. That's why we have introduced that artificial `BatchingRabbitTemplate` to batch on the application level, before protocol.